# Bubble Sort slower in Open MP

Tags: c++, sorting, openmp, bubble-sort

the bubble sorting program i wrote in openMP is slower than the serial version of this, why is this, i cant understand whats the problem.

On serial version it takes around 0.07 and on parallel it takes around 0.9 for an array of 5000 elements

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *num1, int *num2)
{
    
    int temp = *num1;
    *num1 =  *num2;
    *num2 = temp;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int SIZE =5000;
    int A[SIZE];
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        A[i]=rand()%SIZE;
    }
    int N = SIZE;
    int i=0, j=0; 
    int first;
    double start,end;
    start=omp_get_wtime();
        
    #pragma omp parallel reduction( +:first )

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {

        first = i % 2; 
        
        #pragma omp parallel for default(none),shared(A,first,N)

        for( j = first; j < N-1; j += 2 )
        {
            
            if( A[ j ] > A[ j+1 ] )
            {
                swap( &A[ j ], &A[ j+1 ] );
            }
            
            
        }
            
    }
    
    
end=omp_get_wtime();
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d",A[i]);
    }

printf("\n-------------------------\n Time Parallel= %f",(end-start));
}
```

Comment: probably the sample you are using is too small to make worth the time the pc has to use to create multiple thread, try using 500000 elements

Comment: Note that in buble sort second iteration depends on first iteration and so on. So it naive palatalization like you have wrote can't work.

Comment: your program has data races, you have shared(A) but you modify it in the parallel region

Comment: Moreover, you have nested parallelism, you probably wanted #pragma omp for instead of #pragma omp parallel for

Comment: i tried what you guys suggested, but still its bad

Comment: Parallelism isn't some magic that makes your code faster. Most sorting algorithms aren't easily parallelized or don't give good parallel performance. That is why there are special sorting algorithms for use in parallel computing (they probably perform badly when used sequantially). If you want to learn OpenMP sorting isn't the best corner to do so. If you want faster sorting, bubblesort isn't the algorithm you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to delete the line

```
 #pragma omp parallel reduction( +:first )
```

This line is a mistake as it runs the algorithm several times, but if
you skip this line the algorithm runs correctly in parallel and will be faster using openMP, please check [these slides](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Emjb/cs475/Handouts/bubblesort.2pp.pdf).